# input type='date' defaults to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: html, date, format

I wonder why the date defaults to `mm/dd/yyyy` format in the html input type field? It works like this in Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

```
<input type='date' name='$key' value='$val'><br>
```

Is there a simple way to change this into `dd/mm/yyyy` or `yyyy/mm/dd`, which seems more logical to me?

Comment: try to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: You may want to use a text input with a pattern to make the format crossbrowsers

Comment: This answer isn't answered... his problem is variable $val which is set to format mm/dd/yyyy. It has nothing to do with date type of input field. @Alive to die